# gnuplot: robust plot range

Tags: gnuplot

Often outliers are present in data set.
gnuplot uses the minimum and the maximum of the data for autoscaling.
But any ideas how to make the scaling robust against outliers? I'm thinking about `bind` and a function that computes quantiles/percentiles.

```
array DATA[1000]
do for [i=1:1000] {DATA[i]=invnorm(rand(0))}
DATA[42] = 1e7

pl DATA pt 7
pl [][-4:4] DATA pt 7
```

[image]

After a lot of interactive zooming or manual adjusting of the plot range:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `stats` command will report quartiles.  You could bind a keystroke to rescale on y using the previous result from `stats`.  Using the median +/- 1.5 * (inter-quartile range) would give the same overall range as the default whisker bars on a `boxplot`.

```
bind 'S' 'set yrange [ STATS_median_y - 1.5 * (STATS_up_quartile_y-STATS_lo_quartile_y) : STATS_median_y + 1.5 * (STATS_up_quartile_y-STATS_lo_quartile_y) ]; replot'

stats DATA using 1:2
plot DATA using 1:2
pause -1 "Type 'S' in plot window to rescale"
```

Compare this to

```
plot DATA using 1:2 with boxplot
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. The [interquartile range](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interquartile_range) corresponds to 2*0.6744 sigma in a Gaussian distribution. Times 1.5 is 1.01 sigma, which I find to aggressive. For 3 sigma the factor is `2.22`.

Comment: I think you dropped a factor of 2 there.  The interquartile range of a Gaussian is 1.35 sigma,  so 1.5 times that is 2.03 sigma.